# Parameterize set-returning function with column in the same query

Tags: postgresql

Essentially, what I want to do is:

```
SELECT set_returning_func(id) FROM my_table;
```

However, the result will be a single column in record syntax, e.g.

```
             set_returning_func              
---------------------------------------------
 (old,17,"August    2, 2011 at 02:54:59 PM")
 (old,28,"August    4, 2011 at 08:03:12 AM")
(2 rows)
```

I want it to be unpacked into columns.  If I write the query this way instead:

```
SELECT srf.* FROM my_table, set_returning_func(my_table.id);
```

I get an error message:

```
ERROR:  function expression in FROM cannot refer to other relations of same query level
```

How, then, do I get a result set, while also supplying the set-returning function with an argument?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax I was looking for is:

```
SELECT (set_returning_func(id)).* FROM my_table;
```

#### Details

`set_returning_func(id)` is of composite type.  Just as the `*` syntax can be used on tables:

```
SELECT my_table.* FROM my_table, my_other_table
```

It can also be used on composite values (though they must be wrapped in parentheses).  Intuitively, one can also select individual columns from a composite-returning function:

```
SELECT (set_returning_func(id)).time FROM my_table;
```

Some set-returning functions have a scalar rather than composite return type.  In these cases, the `(expr).*` syntax doesn't make sense, and produces an error:

```
> SELECT (generate_series(1,5)).*;
ERROR:  type integer is not composite
```

The correct syntax is simply:

```
> SELECT generate_series(1,5);
 generate_series 
-----------------
               1
               2
               3
               4
               5
(5 rows)
```

Comment: As a fairly esoteric addendum, this also means you can do `select table from table` to get a single column result containing full `table` rows.